# How to restrict users without permissions when using remote auth backend?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am relatively new to Django. I am user a remote auth backend, but I am wondering if there is a way that I can restrict users that do not have permissions, gotten from REMOTE_USER. Is it similar to the way you do it with a Django Auth system?

Right now everyone who is logged in on my auth backend can access my site.

I want to grant certain users permissions before they login, and deny all other users. Is there a way in which I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's standard user model has `is_staff` and `is_superuser` attributes that can easily be toggled.

If you use your `remote auth backend` for authentication and are still using the django `User` model you can easily re-use some of this built-in functionality, such as the `staff_member_required` decorator:

```
    from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

    @staff_member_required
    def staff_view(request..):
        ...
```

Comment: Thank You, That is what I am looking for!